# Unable to access camera after adding plugin and feature and use permission in phonegap android project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to access my camera in Android phone.

I did all steps but still unable to access. I am using latest phonegap and I have installed all plugins and I have added permission in `manifest.xml` file and added features in `config.xml`.

Following are my files.

**HTML**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
         <title>Capture Photo</title>

         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

         var pictureSource;   // picture source
         var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
       //
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {

         alert('onDeviceReady!');
        alert('navigator = ' + navigator);
        alert('navigator.camera = ' + navigator.camera);
        alert('navigator.camera.DestinationType = ' + navigator.camera.DestinationType);
        //                pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;            //                        navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        alert('destinationType = ' + destinationType);

        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;

         alert('onDeviceReady! after');


    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
        // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
        // console.log(imageData);

        // Get image handle
        //
        alert("onphotodatasuccess.");
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // Uncomment to view the image file URI
        // console.log(imageURI);

        // Get image handle
        //
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

        // Unhide image elements
        //
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Show the captured photo
        // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
        //
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
        alert("hi");
        // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
        });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
        // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded     string
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
            destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
        });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        alert("get photo.");
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source
        });
        alert("get photo done.");
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
 <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
 <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
 <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
 <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
 <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
 <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

**`Androidmanifest.xml`**

```
             <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
              <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1"       android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.inf.cameracheck"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
             <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true"   android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true"   android:xlargeScreens="true" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
           <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
           <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
           <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"    android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"  android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="camchk" andr  oid:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
          </activity>
       </application>
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
           </manifest>
```

**`config.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.inf.cameracheck" version="1.0.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
    <access origin="*" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <name>camchk</name>
    <description>Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.</description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-  173.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.devicemotion.AccelListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.deviceorientation.CompassListener" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Comment: @DiveshSalian, there is no error. it build & run successfully in my phone, but when i press any of button. it does not function at all. but when i run it and try to click buttons, i got some error in eclipse logcat window.  thank you

Comment: errors : 03-07 16:38:39.760: E/Web Console(21880): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PictureSourceType' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/main.js:18
03-07 16:44:21.810: E/Web Console(21880): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FILE_URI' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/main.js:65
 E/Web Console(21880): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/main.js:123
E/Web Console(21880): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SAVEDPHOTOALBUM' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:297

Comment: after adding the camera plugin did u build the project ????

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your javascript code into this

```
var pictureSource; // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// device APIs are available
//

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
    // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
    // console.log(imageData);
    // Get image handle
    //
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    // Unhide image elements
    //
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';
    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    smallImage.src = imageURI;
}
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    // Uncomment to view the image file URI
    // console.log(imageURI);
    // Get image handle
    //
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    // Unhide image elements
    //
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    largeImage.src = imageURI;
}
// A button will call this function
//

function capturePhoto() {
    // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI
    });
}
// A button will call this function
//

function capturePhotoEdit() {
    // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 20,
        allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
    });
}
// A button will call this function
//

function getPhoto(source) {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source
    });
}
// Called if something bad happens.
//

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```